# Why is $gcd(2n-1, 2n^2-1) = 1$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Why is 
$$gcd(2n-1, 2n^2-1) = 1$$
?

My first idea is, 
that 
$$2n^2-1 = n^2 + (n-1)(n+1) $$
and
$$2n-1 = n + (n-1)$$

But I can't make use of this. This seems to have something to do with polynomials, I gues.

Comment: Try using polynomial division to divide $2n^2-1$ by $2n-1$. If it has no remainder, that means that $k(2n-1) = 2n^2-1$ for some $k$, which makes the $GCD$ not $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$gcd(2n-1,2n^2-1)=gcd(2n-1,2n^2-2n)=gcd(2n-1,2n(n-1))=1$$
Because $$gcd(2n-1,2)=gcd(2n-1,n)=gcd(2n-1,n-1)=gcd(n,n-1)=1.$$

Comment: Why is $gcd(2n−1,2n(n−1))=1$ ?

Comment: Because $gcd(2n-1,2)=1$, $gcd(2n-1,n)=1$ and $(2n-1,n-1)=1$. See please better my solution.

Comment: And why is $gcd(2n−1,2n^2−1)=gcd(2n−1,2n^2−2n)$ ?

Comment: Because $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,a-b).$

Comment: Wait what is $a$ and $b$ then?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $1=(2n+1)(2n-1)-2(2n^2-1)$

Answer (score 0):

Mark $d=gcd(2n-1,2n^2-1)$.

Then $d|2n^2-1$ and $d|2n-1$. From second we get $d|(2n-1)n =2n^2-n$ so $$d|(2n^2-1)-(2n^2-n) =n-1$$
So we have $d|2n-2$ and now we have $$d|(2n-1)-(2n-2) =1$$
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

With simple congruences:

Let $d$ be a common divisor. Saying that $d$ divides both $2n-1$ and  $2n^2-1$ means $2n\equiv 1 $ and $2n^2\equiv 1 \mod d$.

However $2n^2=(2n)n\equiv 1\cdot n=n$. But then $1\equiv 2n^2\equiv 2\mod d$, and
$$1\equiv 2\mod d\iff d=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Credits to lhf:
$$gcd(2n-1, 2n^2-1) = gcd\big(2n-1, (2n-1)(2n+1)-2(2n^2-1)\big) = gcd(2n-1, 1) = 1 $$
since $$ 1=(2n+1)(2n−1)−2(2n²−1)$$